# How to convert this to a string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple visual calculator and if you press 1 on it it currently just adds the number to it that would mean that 1+1 is 2. I want it to be 11. How do I do this? How will my code look after I did it?

```
{
    double value1 = 0;
    double value2 = 0;
    double finalResult = 0;
    double output = 0;
    bool second = false;
    bool plus = false;
    bool minus = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 1;
            output = value1 * 10 + 1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 1;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 2;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 2;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 3;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 3;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 4;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 4;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 5;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 5;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 6;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 6;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 7;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 7;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 8;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 8;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (second == false)
        {
            value1 = value1 + 9;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (second == true)
        {
            value2 = value2 + 9;
            output = value2;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //remember to add all the other values :)
        value1 = 0;
        value2 = 0;
        finalResult = 0;
        output = 0;
        second = false;
        plus = false;
        minus = false;
        textresult.Text = output.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output = 0;
        textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        second = true;
        plus = true;
    }

    private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        output = 0;
        textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        second = true;
        minus = true;
    }

    private void buttonIs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (plus == true)
        {
            finalResult = value1 + value2;
            output = finalResult;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
        else if (minus == true)
        {
            finalResult = value1 - value2;
            output = finalResult;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `value1.ToString() + value2.ToString()` will concatenate the numbers instead of adding them.

Comment: `yourInt.ToString() + yourOtherInt.ToString()`

Comment: Instead of having `result = 1 + 2` which would be `3` (numeric addition), you'd need `result = 1.ToString() + 2.ToString()` which is `12` (string addition)

Comment: @ChristopherLake I guess I was too slow!

Comment: It's unfair to expect us to read through and solve your problem when you haven't even named your controls to something more useful like `btnAdd`, `btnSubtract` etc.

Comment: I hardly recommend to get familiar with methods...would make your code alot more readable and refactoring alot easier.

Comment: It gives me a error https://gyazo.com/309ca488ae3a55dfd02d8f6dcbbfff13

Comment: @RobinWithes put breakpoints and go through your code one by one using F11. That way you can identify which line gives the error.

Comment: In order to make 1 + 1 = 11, 1 should be string. If 1 is numerical type then 1+1 = 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert int - string with this.

```
int i = 1;
string s = Convert.ToString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share a some ideas/recommendations to simplify your code

```
enum Operators
{
    NewOperation = -1,
    NotSet = 0,
    Plus = 1,
    Minus = 2
    //...
};

int value1, value2;
const string RESET_VALUE = "0";
Operators operation;

public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { textresult.Text = RESET_VALUE; }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(1); }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(2); }
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(3); }
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(4); }
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(5); }
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(6); }
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(7); }
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(8); }
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(9); }
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { AppendNumber(0); }

private void AppendNumber(int selected_number)
{
    if (operation == Operators.NewOperation)
    {
        operation = Operators.NotSet;
        textresult.Text = $"{selected_number}";         
    }
    else if (textresult.Text.StartsWith("0")) 
    { 
        textresult.Text = $"{selected_number}"; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        textresult.Text = $"{textresult.Text}{selected_number}";
    }

    if (operation == Operators.NotSet)
        value1 = int.Parse(textresult.Text);
    else
        value2 = int.Parse(textresult.Text);
}
private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operation = Operators.Plus;
    textresult.Text = RESET_VALUE;
}
private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operation = Operators.Minus;
    textresult.Text = RESET_VALUE;
}
private void buttonIs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case Operators.Minus: textresult.Text = $"{(value1 - value2)}"; break;
        case Operators.Plus: textresult.Text = $"{(value1 + value2)}"; break;
    }

    operation = Operators.NewOperation;
    value1 = int.Parse(textresult.Text); //save result for next operation
    value2 = 0;
}
private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    operation = Operators.NotSet;
    textresult.Text = RESET_VALUE;
    value1 = value2 = 0;
}
```